# Google Calendar API expiration time for refresh_token?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

In my nodejs server I am using '@google-cloud/local-auth' library to create events in calendar,
when I authenticate to google calendar it returns me a client with refresh_token. What is the expiration time for this refresh_token?

```
  public async authorize(): Promise<any> {
    let authClient: any = await this.getSavedCredentialsIfExist();
    if (authClient) {
      return authClient;
    }

    authClient = await authenticate({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
      keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH
    });

    console.log('authClient', authClient);

    if (authClient?.credentials) {
      await this.saveCredentials(authClient.credentials.refresh_token);
    }
    return authClient;
  }
```

Returned Client details:

```
{
   "type":"authorized_user",
   "client_id":"***",
   "client_secret":"***",
   "refresh_token":"***"
}
```

I looked at Google Calendar API documentation and didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [oauth2#expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration)

Refresh tokens are designed to be long lived and should not expire.  For google though there are a few ways they can expire.

- The user has revoked your app's access.
- The refresh token has not been used for six months.
- The user changed passwords and the refresh token contains Gmail scopes.
- The user account has exceeded a maximum number of granted (live) refresh tokens.
- If an admin set any of the services requested in your app's scopes to Restricted (the error is admin_policy_enforced).
- For Google Cloud Platform APIs - the session length set by the admin could have been exceeded.

A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen configured for an external user type and a publishing status of **"Testing"** is issued a `refresh token expiring in 7 days`, unless the only OAuth scopes requested are a subset of name, email address, and user profile (through the userinfo.email, userinfo.profile, openid scopes, or their OpenID Connect equivalents).

Note on the last part this is testing not verification.